# Webstorm node.js remote debugging will not jump to breakpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, webstorm, angular-fullstack

I am using angular-fullstack generator and Webstorm 10.

The node.js remote debug configuration:

```
 localhost: 127.0.0.1
 port: 5858
```

When I enter 'grunt serve:debug':

```
Debugger listening on port 5858
Node Inspector v0.9.2
Visit http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.
Express server listening on 9000, in development mode
```

At this point localhost:8080/debug?port=5858 opens, I then start my node.js remote debugger. It says:

```
 Connected to localhost:5858
```

Yet, the frames pane is completely blank and all breakpoints are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple issues there, related to WebStorm, Grunt, Node itself... In general, to be able to debug the server-side code of your angular-fullstack application, I'd suggest the following:

Use Node.js run configuration to debug:

```
Working directory: your project root folder
 JavaScript file: path/to/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
 Application parameters: serve
```

Add the following line to the top of your Gruntfile.js;

```
process.execArgv = [];
```

This should fix problem debugging Grunt child processes -  by default, the spawned child process uses the same debug port as a parent process - as a result the forked process is suspended and the application 'stalls'.
Also, open node_modules\grunt-express-server\tasks\lib\server.js and change line 71 to:

```
options.opts.unshift('--debug-brk');
```

When a child process is spawned with --debug option instead of --debug-brk, WebStorm debugger doesn't always have time to register a breakpoint when the process starts, and thus breakpoints in child process are not hit.

Instructions are written for application generated with  generator-angular-fullstack@2.0.13; you might have a different setup...